# Refusal and a 10 year ban for an entry clearance

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, nigerian-citizens, fraud

I had applied for a visit visa in March 2018 for my graduation in the UK but was refused on ground of deception. At the time I made the application, I was in the Nigerian law school so I contracted a visa agent to make the application for me. I had given him my passport and all the relevant information necessary for a successful outcome, but unfortunately for me, he failed to provide all my travelling details in my application. Out of about 6 inbound and outbound flights from the UK, he provided the immigration with only two ( my last two inbound and outbound). In all honesty i failed to look at his job meticulously before affixing my signature and submitting the application.For this reason, I was denied a visa and sadly, I missed the opportunity to attend my graduation. I just got an admission for an LLM programme in the UK but my counsellor confirmed that indeed I have a 10 year ban. The refusal letter states that future entry will be considered on their individual merits...and that I may be refused for a period of up 10 years depending on the type of application I make...[image]!

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84720/discussion-on-question-by-nshimina-refusal-and-a-10-year-ban-for-an-entry-cleara).

Comment: @greatone my passport has all the stamps of my flights in and out of the UK. The form that was filled might have been the old one.

Comment: I don't see this as deception. You should hire a solicitor and challenge the decision by judicial review. For a start: OPl177lssued 2009 "e.g. an applicant has ticked that
they have not previously been refused a UK visa, but has presented a passport containing a refusal stamp and/or a previous refusal notice. This should not be considered to be deception" The main grounds for the judicial review would be that they did not follow their own guidelines. I don't think the ECO has been able to show you were dishonest. You have a very good shot. Do let us know what happens.

Comment: You submitting the passport with the real dates show that you were not attempting to deceive the ECO. There were stamps that already show that you overstayed. If you wanted to hide that overstay, you would not have submitted that passport at all. That would make the decision unlawful.

Comment: @greatone The UK does not stamp passports on exiting the country; how can his passport stamps show that he overstayed?

Comment: @mdd since 2014, the UK collects exit data from airlines.

Comment: Thank you all. Please is it possible for an experienced Nigerian lawyer to apply to the Uk for a judicial review or it must be a practicing legal practitioner in the Uk?

Comment: http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/search/results?UmbrellaLegalIssue=LIUIMM&Location=Nigeria&Pro=False

Comment: @greatone Sure, but nothing in his passport itself indicates when he left the country or if he overstayed. So the OP can’t use the argument that the information was available in the passport as an excuse for not providing the details of his previous stays and overstay.

Comment: @mdd umm there are things called stamps. Even if the UK doesn't stamp passports on exit, it is highly likely that the country he traveled to did stamp on entry. It's not an excuse. It's part of evidence to try and show he wasn't dishonest. If he really wanted to hide his travel history, he would have got a new passport. The standard of proof here is a balance of probabilities so it has to be more likely than not that the OP intentionally used deception. I don't have to make the decision but I'll give the OP the edge here.

Answer (score 12):

You signed a document which you didn't check and sent it to British immigration. I forget the wording but you would have certified your application as 'true and complete' which clearly it wasn't.

I find it unlikely that the immigration officer would find deception for leaving off details of a couple of flights. They'd have used some lesser form of words to refuse you, so it seems that your agent has included something more serious, or omitted something significant that should have been included. Have you been refused entry before? Whatever, you are held responsible for what the agent supplied because you signed it.

Now you have a ten year ban. It will not be easy to get this waived. If it was there'd be no point in imposing it. You can forget about going to Britain any time soon. Even after the ban has expired you will probably find it difficult to get a visa to visit the UK.

You have few options, and they are all expensive. You should consult a good lawyer with experience in difficult UK immigration cases. He should be able to give you an assessment of your chances. If he can see a case for arguing that the ban is incorrect you might be in with a chance but you'll need plenty of money and you won't get a solution in the short term, or maybe not at all.

Don't go to a Nigerian 'visa agent' - that's what got you into this pickle.

What's worse is that you'll have to disclosed this refusal and ban on visa applications to other countries, and that will make getting those visas harder too.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84729/discussion-on-answer-by-cannon-fodder-refusal-and-a-10-year-ban-for-an-entry-cle).

Comment: @MusoniusRufus I was not afraid of refusal because I over stayed. I only got an agent for expert service so as to avoid mistakes made by visa applicants.