# Is this an entry ban?

Tags: uk, denial-of-entry

I got an entry refusal but I would like to know if it is an entry ban.

The letter states:

> You have sought leave to enter the UK as a visitor.
>
> However you have admitted that during your previous visit to the UK
>   between 15 September 2016 and 5 March 2017, you took employment as an
>   au-pair for a family who are friends of your family. *< snip of payment
>   details >* You did not tell this me when I first spoke to you and only
>   admitted it when my colleague found your contract of employment in your
>   bag.
>
> You state that your parents have been supporting you by sending you
>   approximately *< snip of payment details >* but you have not been able
>   to show any evidence of this support. You do not have a ticket to
>   return to Mexico. You state you will purchase one. You state *< personal funding
>   details >*. Again you have not been able to show any evidence of these
>   funds.
>
> You insist that you will not take employment on this occasion.
>   However, given your previous disregard for the immigration rules, I am
>   not satisfied that you will not seek to do the same this time.
>
> I am not satified that you are a genuine visitor as required by
>   paragraph V 4.2 of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for Visitors. You are
>   therefore refused entry to the UK.
>
> You have not sought entry under any other provisions under the
>   immigration rules.
>
> I therefore refuse you leave to enter the United Kingdom.

Comment: It is unwise to put personally identifying official documents on the internet.

Comment: I can't propose an edit now because there's already a pending one, but a better title would be: "Is an entry refusal an entry ban?" You could also add "and being removed from the control zone", if that's relevant (I'm not sure what it means).

Comment: The "Control Zone" in this case would appear to be the [Eurotunnel Calais Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurotunnel_Calais_Terminal) - (address is Coquelles near Calais) which operates as a [clearing house for border controls before embarking on the Eurostar train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juxtaposed_controls).

Comment: @ouflak why is that?

Comment: @ouflak editing the question doesn't eliminate those personal details.  It merely puts them one click away.  I'm not sure how to actually purge them though.

Comment: @PeterM, I know. There should really be a facility to do that. I think it's been a feature request.

Comment: @ouflak I raised [this issue](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6406/6188) on the Meta site and the answer is to flag it for moderation

Answer (score 20):

No, there is no evidence of a ban being placed on the traveller in that refusal, but it does document an incidence of deception during the interview, and now that is on file it could be used to support a ban being put into place during any weak subsequent applications.

[UK immigration bans are very very explicitly laid out in refusal letters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124303/refusal-and-a-10-year-ban-for-an-entry-clearance), and state unequivocally and clearly that a ban is in place - that is not so in this case, unless there are further pages to this refusal that you haven't uploaded.

Comment: and given the wording of the letter, it seems likely that any future attempt to enter the UK without very good supporting paperwork will lead to a ban... Repeated attempts to enter the UK under suspicious or false stated reasons are not appreciated

Comment: @jwenting I wouldn’t doubt that, but in other cases we have seen here that’s normally mentioned in the refusal, and here it isn’t.  I wouldn’t fancy my chances tho if it were me....

Comment: yeah. Was only adding an extra warning for OP to not try again to get to the UK without having all his documentation perfectly in order.

Comment: Also, a ban typically states for how long it will stay in effect, doesn't it?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/difference-between-deportation-and-removal/60241#60241

Comment: @Traveller How is that related?

Comment: @Moo It talks about ‘removal from port’ and about the effect on entering the UK in future.